# Configure automount vboxsf in 15.04

Tags: mount, 15.04

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 over VirtualBox 4.3.28.

I have a shared folder using `vboxsf`. Until now, adding the `mount -t vboxsf` command in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file, it was mounted automatically on startup, but not any more.  However, if I execute the command in a terminal, it works fine.

On my previous version there is no problem with this, but now it doesn't work on startup and no message showed.

*How should I proceed?*